# How do you test pages that require authentication with Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit

I need to test a web application using Selenium. The app is fairly common in its setup: it requires signing in for most of the functionality to be exposed. Upon loading a page, if the user is not authenticated, it will redirect to a login form and then back to the requested page once credentials are supplied.

What's the usual way to go around this with Selenium? I take it people are not logging in on every single test as this would cause significant overhead on big test suites. Is there a way to set up a session in a test and then use the cookie information for subsequent tests, or do a conditional sign-in (without incurring in massive code repetition!)?

I am using PHPUnit with Selenium ATM.

Thank you!

Gonzalo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm using C#+NUnit+Selenium RC)

Most of the time, each test goes through the login form. However, if I'm writing a series of tests that are very short (< 10 seconds each) and there are a lot of them, I usually share the same browser instance across tests by moving the selenium start\close calls from the SetUp\TearDown methods to the Test Fixture SetUp\TearDown methods. This avoids the cost of re-authenticating as well as the cost of launching a new browser every time. I'm sure you can do something similar with PHPUnit.

Comment: Do you think its an easier way to create a profile for your tests and then complete the authentication manually in that profile before the tests are triggered? So that when your tests starts and invokes this profile, you are already logged in?

Comment: @AJ77 I don't really know, I use Selenium to automate IE almost exclusively and as far as I know, IE doesn't support a "profile" feature like you are suggesting. Most websites use some kind of cookie to store session ASP.NET's (I'm testing a web-forms app) session cookies expire rather quickly so even if we could store cookies across browser instances, it would expire too quickly to be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

If this is basic http auth you can use the username/password with the url request as documented in the Selenium FAQ: [http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIuseSeleniumtologintositesthatrequireHTTPbasicauthentication%28wherethebrowsermakesamodaldialogaskingforcredentials%29%3F](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIuseSeleniumtologintositesthatrequireHTTPbasicauthentication%28wherethebrowsermakesamodaldialogaskingforcredentials%29?)

> How do I use Selenium to login to
>   sites that require HTTP basic
>   authentication (where the browser
>   makes a modal dialog asking for
>   credentials)?
>
> Use a username and password in the
>   URL, as described in RFC 1738: Test
>   Type        open
>     http://myusername:myuserpassword@myexample.com/blah/blah/blah
>
> Note that on Internet Explorer this
>   won't work, since Microsoft has
>   disabled usernames/passwords in URLs
>   in IE. However, you can add that
>   functionality back in by modifying
>   your registry, as described in the
>   linked KB article. Set an
>   "iexplore.exe" DWORD to 0 in
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE.
>
> If you don't want to modify the
>   registry yourself, you can always just
>   use Selenium Remote Control, which
>   automatically sets that that registry
>   key for you as of version 0.9.2.

Comment: No, I meant the standard cookie-based session mechanism used on pretty much every website nowadays.